# Why is Chi-Chi less of a a nag on Goten?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

Re-watching Dragon Ball Z I have noticed that Chi-Chi's main goal in DBZ was to stop Gohan from training and force him to study instead. But once the Cell arc finishes and Goten is born. Chi-Chi doesn't treat him the same way.

It blew my mind that she even let him train at all but apparently through training with her Goten was able to transform into a super saiyan.

My question is why? Is it because Goku officially passed on so her character developed a bit? I never actually actuallly thought about it until now.

Comment: I thought Chi-Chi herself explained this: Gohan was a docile and peaceful child--early on, all he does in a conflict situation is cry and ask for his mom and dad, until eventually going berserk; whereas Goten was energetic and combative (in a "good" way).  So she accepted his nature, knew he was going to get into this sort of thing regardless, and worked with it as best as she could to guide him. Gohan was always a reluctant warrior.  He had great power, but he only ever learned fighting out of necessity, and would have preferred not doing so.  Goten fought because he wanted to.

Comment: There could be one another reason that Chi-Chi saw Goku in Goten as Goten does resemble Goku when he was a child. And for this reason, she personally trained Goten, so he could be as strong as his father!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take is basically the same as those commercials that start with the worried obsessive mother and the first child:  She is so frantic about everything she ends up messing things up.

Second child happens, and she has everything nailed down.  Experience from the first child has her less stressed with the second child, and she knows a bit of what to expect and how to handle things.